# How can I get the value of an input which is a previous sibling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to switch a background image with a URL from a input field. With one block it works, for a second it only works if I use the first one first, or else it gets a undefined value. How do I grab the `ImageUrl` value for each block only?

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $(".Btn").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).closest('.parent').find('.child')
        .css("backgroundImage", "url('" + jQuery(".ImageUrl").val() + "')");
  });
});
```

```css
.child {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  background-size: cover;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="switch">
      <input class="ImageUrl"> <span class="Btn">Go</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="switch">
      <input class="ImageUrl"> <span class="Btn">Go</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you use a snippet, then **always** use the _"Tidy"_ option.

Comment: Find the correct `.ImageUrl` similarly to how you find the correct `.child`

Comment: Thanks @Andreas - not sure how to store it correctly but ill give it a go.

Comment: Tip: a `<span>` is not a `<button>`  This will make your life much easier in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to traverse the DOM to accomplish this. Here's one.

Note that I've made your button an actual button. This is important for accessibility (and good semantics in general). Style accordingly. You could also apply `aria-role="button"` to a span if you prefer.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $(".switch button").click(function() {
    const imgUrl = $(this).prev('input').val();

    $(this).closest('.parent').find('.child')
      .css("backgroundImage", "url('" + imgUrl + "')");
  });
});
```

```css
.child {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  background-size: cover;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="switch">
      <input value="https://via.placeholder.com/400"> <button>Go</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="switch">
      <input value="https://via.placeholder.com/400"> <button>Go</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```